# Converting Google Sheets (Apps Scripts) to a valid CSV format

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets

I have the below script which essentially looks at a google sheets tab, which has some data that needs to be uploaded to Google Import API (Google Analytics):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('UK Only');
  var maxRows = ss.getLastRow();
  var maxColumns = ss.getLastColumn();
  var rows = ss.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, maxColumns).getValues();
  var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n")

  var blobData = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, "application/octet-stream", "GA import data");
  try {
    var upload = Analytics.Management.Uploads.uploadData("10131233", "UA-1234576-2", "righfghfghfgT8Dox1nwXDg", blobData);
    Logger.log("Test Data Import Successful");
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

The output is something like the below:

```
ga:productSku,ga:productName,ga:productBrand,ga:productCategoryHierarchy,ga:dimension25,ga:dimension28,ga:dimension31
456456456,example value wit,h char ,that "breaks" csv,fgjfgjf Tjghjghjg,FP,Women,dasdasd
456456456,example value wit,h char ,that "breaks" csv,123123123,FP,Women,dasdasd
456456456,example value wit,h char ,that "breaks" csv,Rdasdasd,FP,asdasdasd
```

The above shows some values that will break the CSV format (commas and quotes).

How do I go about properly formatting the CSV so that it will not break on these characters?

Comment: Yes, open it in excel and other products, works as it should. But Google API parses the commas in rows as columns, so when there's a value that contains commas, it will parses that too.

Comment: Can you wrap it in quotes?

Comment: That's what it says in the docs to do, so every value should be wrapped in quotes (i.e. "val1","val2" etc.). The problem is, I couldn't figure out a way to do it per value, managed to do it per row (i.e."val1,val2") , but not per value.

Comment: so .getRange returns a Range, and Range.getValues returns a 2D array. You can DIY and map through the 2D array and wrap everything in quotes. Here's something that might help you, the function at line 44. https://gist.github.com/mrkrndvs/a2c8ff518b16e9188338cb809e06ccf1#file-export-named-sheet-as-csv-gs-L44

Comment: Use a chain of `Array#map` calls & `Array#join` to apply a function to each inner element and combine the results. This allows simple specification of the separator, the line ending, and the quote behavior (e.g. minimal, all, non-numeric).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this with the below function, I had to account for quotes and commas within values that Google API doesn't like:

```
function arrayToCSV (twoDiArray) {
    var csvRows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < twoDiArray.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < twoDiArray[i].length; ++j) {
            twoDiArray[i][j] = '\"' + twoDiArray[i][j].replace('"','""') + '\"';
        }
        csvRows.push(twoDiArray[i].join(','));
    }

    return csvRows.join('\r\n');
};
```

Making sure to call it with the below:

```
  var maxRows = ss.getLastRow();
  var maxColumns = ss.getLastColumn();
  var rows = ss.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, maxColumns).getValues();
  var rowsCSV = arrayToCSV(rows);
```